# Customised Twitter Feed on website

Tags: html, css, web, twitter, twitter-feed

I am creating a website for a customer who would like a Twitter feed on their page. I am aware of the standard Twitter feed via the embedded code on Twitter or via the various plug ins however they do not allow me to customise the feed to the extent I would like to customise it to. I have attached an image to this post. Is it possible to fully style a feed like this? The caption image is not an issue as I can make it the background image but is the rest possible?

[image: Image of Twitter Feed]

Andi

Answer (score 0):

Use rest api from twitter you will get json and can format them how ever you want.
Use the rest api console of twitter here.
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console
If you are not sure how rest APIs work please do a google for that